# Updating iOS version with baseband damaged

Tags: iphone

I just want to ask if it is okay to update the iOS version even though my baseband is damaged? My iPhone 6 service network keeps on “searching”.

Answer (score 1):

> if it is okay to update my ios version even though my baseband is damaged

Yes.

It is generally a good idea to update to publicly available version of iOS. The current latest version available for iPhone 6 should be iOS 12.4.2 which is a security and bug fix release.